# How do I identify an instance of a class by a variable assigned to the instance in Java?

Tags: java, class, instance

I am somewhat new to programming in general, and I have been experimenting with procedural generation, more specifically with Strings. As of right now, I have classes for vowels and consonants, I have instanced every letter of the alphabet, and I have written class methods within vowel.java and consonant.java to return the character itself, to return what type of letter the character is, and to add the character to a string. Everything works so far, but I do not know how to identify an instance of each class based on a variable assigned to it. Here is a block of code to make my words a little more clear.

```
package procgensentence;

public class ProcGenSentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String product = "";
        //Class Objects
        vowel a = new vowel(1, 'a');
        consonant b = new consonant(2, 'b');
        consonant c = new consonant(3, 'c');
        consonant d = new consonant(4, 'd');
        vowel e  = new vowel(5, 'e');
        consonant f = new consonant(6, 'f');
    }
}
```

I want to be able to identify each instance later on by the character assigned to it, so that later on when I am testing whether or not the previous character in the String product was a consonant or a vowel, to determine what type the next character should be, I can properly use my .returnType method for the correct character.

Comment: Remark: In Java, class names should always start with an uppercase letter. There are some possibilities that come to mind. The first one would be to write a own `Letter` class. Give this class a method `public boolean isVowel()` and/or `public boolean isConsonant()`. You can query this method to get your answer. Then, you could to turn this in a [Multition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) and/or provide [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: The code it illegible. When writing code, and especially when posting on public fora, **use Java naming conventions**.

Comment: I'm voting close as "too broad" because if I understand your question correctly, there are a lot of changes nessecary. Here are some hints on what you could look into: collections/espacially maps, equals/hasCode, subtyping (maybe create a superclass of vowel and constant)

Comment: Alright, thank you for the feedback. Like I said, I am pretty new to Java as a whole, so thank you.

Comment: This seems perfect for the creation of 2 enumerations: Vowel and Consonant. They could implement a general interface for the other requirements (return character itself, type of letter, etc.)

Comment: @JamesRickman you're welcome. Keep at it, programming is hard, especially when you are just starting :-)